# Limit number of items in Dynamo DB or monitor the number of items in Dynamo DB in real time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a pool of users in Dynamo DB and limit the number of users in it.
For that I want to either restrict the number of entries in the table maintaining the pool or create an alarm as soon as the size crosses a threshold.
I know I can monitor the size through DescribeTable operation but it is not real time and updates every 6 hours.
If this isn't possible with Dynamo DB, what other better options are available in AWS meeting this requirements?

Comment: Perhaps use DynamoDB Streams to maintain an item count in another table (so you don't have to DescribeTable every time) and to publish a custom CloudWatch metric for that count, then you can configure an alarm on the count exceeding N.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new DDB table (or use your existing 'pool' table, if you have one) and add an [atomic counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) field to track how many users are in the pool, just be sure to add a condition to your writes so that it fails when the max number of users has been reached.

However, as you queried, Dynamo isn't well suited to this type of problem. A small RDS or ElastiCache instance will both set you back about $11 a month are both more straightforward for managing state like that.